# In Google Sheets, can you apply a regex to a generated range?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a list of UK postcodes, looking roughly like this. Entries may not be unique.

```
A1 1AA
A1 2BC
A1 3PN
B2 4XY
B2 5LH
C3 6NJ
```

They're in a range named `Postcodes`. I've set up the following arrangement to count how many instances of each postcode area (the part before the space) there are.

```
   A                 B (range "PostcodeAreas")        C                       D
1  =SORT(Postcodes)  =REGEXREPLACE($A1, "\s\w+", "")  =UNIQUE(PostcodeAreas)  =COUNTIF(PostcodeAreas, $C1)
```

I've extended the formulas in `B1` and `D1` downwards to cover the data output of the formulas in `A1` and `C1`.

This works, and the output would be this for my example data:

```
   A       B    C   D
1  A1 1AA  A1   A1  3
2  A1 2BC  B2   B2  2
3  A1 3PN  C3   C3  1
4  B2 4XY
5  B2 5LH
6  C3 6NJ
```

Columns `A` and `B`, being workings, aren't relevant to the target audience of the sheet, so I've hidden them. The end result is a nice set of counts in columns `C` and `D`.

All well and good. However, I can't help feeling that this can be optimized a bit. Particularly, I don't like the manually-extended formula in `B1`. Is it possible to write a single formula that applies the regular expression to all of the `SORT()` output? Which I could then perhaps even wrap in the `UNIQUE()`, and eliminate the need for working columns entirely? I've searched around a bit but couldn't quite find an answer.

Comment: For the postal code, wouldnt `(LEFT(A1, 2)` suffice?

Comment: No, my example data is a simplification. The first part of a UK postcode can contain several different patterns of letters or numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your data is in A1:A, try in B1

```
=query(ArrayFormula(iferror(regexextract(A1:A, {"^(.+)\s", "\s(.+)$"}))), "select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 <>'' group by Col1")
```

Comment: Beautiful - ARRAYFORMULA was the key. Thanks very much.